# "Sticking together" in circle collision

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, geometry

I have the following code in my collision test:

```
if (Math.pow(A.x - B.x, 2) + Math.pow(A.y - B.y, 2) <= Math.pow(A.radius + B.radius, 2)) {
    A.x_vel = (A.x_vel * (A.mass - B.mass) + (2 * B.mass * B.x_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
    A.y_vel = (A.y_vel * (A.mass - B.mass) + (2 * B.mass * B.y_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
    B.x_vel = (B.x_vel * (B.mass - A.mass) + (2 * A.mass * A.x_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
    B.y_vel = (B.y_vel * (B.mass - A.mass) + (2 * A.mass * A.y_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
    A.x = A.x + A.x_vel;
    A.y = A.y + A.y_vel;
    B.x = B.x + B.x_vel;
    B.y = B.y + B.y_vel;
}
```

The result is the circles sticking together. How can I solve this? Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/tLpEV/3/ (full screen: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tLpEV/3/show/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the velocity for A first, then you use the changed velocity to calculate the new velocity for B. You need to use the original velocity of A, so store the new velocity for A in temporary variables until you have calculated the velocity for B:

```
var ax = (A.x_vel * (A.mass - B.mass) + (2 * B.mass * B.x_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
var ay = (A.y_vel * (A.mass - B.mass) + (2 * B.mass * B.y_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
B.x_vel = (B.x_vel * (B.mass - A.mass) + (2 * A.mass * A.x_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
B.y_vel = (B.y_vel * (B.mass - A.mass) + (2 * A.mass * A.y_vel)) / (A.mass + B.mass);
A.x_vel = ax;
A.y_vel = ay;
A.x = A.x + A.x_vel;
A.y = A.y + A.y_vel;
B.x = B.x + B.x_vel;
B.y = B.y + B.y_vel;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tLpEV/4/

Comment: Arghhh knew it would be something simple. Thanks :D Edit - will accept this when it lets me in 6 minutes

Comment: It's a little laggy, but apart from that I don't notice anything personally

Comment: @PiTheNumber could you elaborate?

Comment: @PiTheNumber I realised I was checking for collisions before updating instead of after, reversing them makes it look a bit better

Comment: @Consciousness: This calculation seem to work reasonably well for a heads on collision, but it looks strange when the balls are moving almost in the same direction. To get the correct velocity you would have to calculate the angle where the balls meet, and how much of their energy is transfered along that line.

Comment: @Guffa how exactly does it look strange in same-direction collisions? It looks as I'd expect it to; perhaps I expect wrong? Take a look at the newest version, http://fiddle.jshell.net/tLpEV/5/show/

Comment: @Consciousness this version looks better but the circles never touch.

Comment: @Consciousness: You can see the strange bounces for example when a fast moving small ball bounces on a large slow ball. You are calculating the collision in the x-y coordinate system. When two balls bounce, imagine a line between the centers of the balls. Force can only be exchanged in the direction of that line. Recalculate the energy of the balls in a coordinate system arranged along this line, then you can calculate the exchange as a heads on collision using the energy component along the line, the energy component in the other direction is not affected at all.